# new/delete causes access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

Ok, this is perplexing me... The code below is in a DLL, and when my console application calls this code it is suddenly throwing an access violation at the line `delete[] lpBuffer`. I have been using this code all day and have not changed it at all. Until now, it had been working just fine.

**Access Violation Message**

> Unhandled exception at 0x6948b1a5 in rhcopy.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4de1c37f.

**Library Code**

```
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE  0x3FFF

DWORD MyClass::GetFile( LPCSTR lpszRemoteFile, LPCSTR lpszLocalFile )
{
    LPBYTE lpBuffer = NULL;

    // ...

    lpBuffer = new BYTE[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

    // ...

    if( NULL != lpBuffer )
        delete[] lpBuffer;

    // ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

On a side note: I have been thinking about converting `lpBuffer` into a vector. Opinions?

**edit**

I want to thank you guys for your help! But apparently... That's not where the problem is. problem is actually a `printf()` statement in the calling application that occurs right after the call to `GetFile(...)`. I apologize for the confusion. It would seem that Microsoft's Debugging tool is not pointing to the line that caused the error, but rather the last line that executed. I have voted to close the question.

Comment: What is in the "..." sections?

Comment: Show us how `lpBuffer` is used, i.e., what is hidden by the `...`.  Your problem is almost certainly in there.

Comment: Yes, wherever possible replace dynamic memory with RIAA classes like `unique_ptr` and `vector`.

Comment: (1) Deleting null is fine and does nothing, there's no need to check. (2) Use `std::vector<BYTE>`.

Comment: The code seems fine, the obscured parts can somehow mess with the lpBuffer. As for opinions - it really depends on what you are trying to do. This code is ok as long as the buffor you are creating is really needed.

Comment: You most likely changed the contents of `lpBuffer` somewhere in the `...` sections.

Comment: @MooingDuck, generally good advice but not when the objects cross a DLL boundary. The sample code here doesn't cross the boundary so it should be safe. I suppose that goes under the category "wherever possible".

Comment: If its a define, you can use compile time array

Comment: Yes, the contents of lpBuffer are accessed and changed within the second `...`, but I assure you it never tries to access outside of `MAX_PACKET_SIZE`.

Comment: @druciferre: Take the code in your question (I've edited it to be valid code) and paste it over your existing function. If the problem goes away, the `// ...` sections are important. If it doesn't, the error does not lie in this function.

Comment: @druciferre: Why can't you just show us the code between the `new` and the `delete`? You could be doing absolutely anything, like changing where `lpBuffer` points as opposed to modify its contents, and we're not going to know unless we see the code.

Comment: @AusCBloke, because the code would reveal a proprietary manufacturing protocol, and it's quite long...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code you've shown here.

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. The error is not actually in the `delete` but in the code just on either side.
2. You've done something to corrupt the heap, by using an invalid pointer that overwrites some random memory or deleting a pointer more than once.

Neither of these problems would be caught by switching to RAII (i.e. `vector`) in the displayed code, but might improve things if you used them consistently in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why an access violation is caused here given the code posted.

Since the buffer is only referenced locally could you make it a stack variable instead of allocated dynamically?

If it must be a pointer maybe you could use a Boost Smart Pointer instead:

```
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE  0x3FFF

DWORD MyClass::GetFile( LPCSTR lpszRemoteFile, LPCSTR lpszLocalFile )
{

    boost::scoped_array<BYTE> bufferPtr;
    ...
    bufferPtr = boost::scoped_array<BYTE>(new BYTE[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]);
    ...
    //No delete needed

}
```

On the vector point, if it's easy to work with a vector I'd opt for it or any other STL Container when you can.